# Home lan network and ip

Tags: port-forwarding, lan, raspberry-pi

I setup a raspberry (wifi connected) in my home lan, accessible also externally from the local network. Since I needed to setup a port forwarding with the raspberry ip my concern is: what if the router decides to assign a different ip to my raspberry? The port forwarding will not work anymore I guess.

Comment: Just assign a static IP to the Pi.

Comment: @mully Can I assign the static ip only from router without configuring raspberry?

Comment: @MarkCryptoCrypto Support for assigning the same IPs to specific devices via your router isn't uncommon but does technically depend on the features of your router (which isn't mentioned here).

Comment: is your router capable of reserving IP addresses based on MAC? most are, but its worth checking. if so, I'd recommend doing that, instead of a static IP. it will ensure that you only assign that address to that station, and centralize control for IP assignment. mixing DHCP and static addresses in the same LAN requires planning beforehand, to create a pool that excludes the static addresses, so if you are already using DHCP for the rest of the LAN, its best to just keep with that. you can do it without rebooting the pi, as . 
Peregrino69 mentions below.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a static IP address to your Raspberry Pi will prevent this from happening,

First, edit the dhcpcd.conf file with `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Scroll all the way to the bottom and add the following:

```
interface eth0

static ip_address=192.168.x.x/24
static routers=192.168.x.x
static domain_name_servers=192.168.x.x
```

Replace the IP address, gateway and DNS with the IP address that you want to use, you might also need to rename `eth0` to the correct interface name.

Once your finished, press `Ctrl+O` to save it, then `Ctrl+X` to exit.

Then type `sudo reboot` to restart your Pi, then once its restarted, type `ip a` to verify that it has the IP address assigned.

Comment: Can I assign the static ip only from router without configuring raspberry?

Comment: Yes - that's usually the way people do it. I wouldn't do it this way. Set static on the gateway & also remove that address from the DHCP pool.

Comment: What happens if I set up in raspberry a static ip but the router already has assigned that one to some other device?

Comment: Then you'll get a race condition - first there gets it, the other will error.

Comment: Check the DHCP pool of the router. To allow static allocations without inducing address duplications it many cases it starts at .100, so .2 - .99 are assignable. The router's DHCP settings also may contain an option to create DHCP reservations, which remove the reserved addresses from the pool for the same purpose.

Comment: Rebooting the RasPi isn't necessary, `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` or restarting the network services also force the adapter to adopt changed settings.